# Assemble paginated ajax data in a Bacon FRP stream

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

I'm learning FRP using Bacon.js, and would like to assemble data from a paginated API in a stream.

The module that uses the data has a consumption API like this:

```
// UI module, displays unicorns as they arrive
beautifulUnicorns.property.onValue(function(allUnicorns){
  console.log("Got "+ allUnicorns.length +" Unicorns");
  // ... some real display work
});
```

The module that assembles the data requests sequential pages from an API and `push`es onto the stream every time it gets a new data set:

```
// beautifulUnicorns module
var curPage = 1
var stream = new Bacon.Bus()
var property = stream.toProperty()
var property.onValue(function(){}) # You have to add an empty subscriber, otherwise future onValues will not receive the initial value. https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/FAQ#why-isnt-my-property-updated

var allUnicorns = [] // !!! stateful list of all unicorns ever received. Is this idiomatic for FRP?

var getNextPage = function(){
  /* get data for subsequent pages.
     Skipping for clarity */
}

var gotNextPage = function (resp) {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(allUnicorns, resp) // just adds the responses to the existing array reference
  stream.push(allUnicorns)
  curPage++
  if (curPage <= pageLimit) { getNextPage() }
}
```

How do I subscribe to the stream in a way that provides me a full list of all unicorns ever received? Is this [`flatMap`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-flatmap) or similar? I don't think I need a new stream out of it, but I don't know. I'm sorry, I'm new to the FRP way of thinking. To be clear, assembling the array works, it just feels like I'm not doing the idiomatic thing.

I'm not using jQuery or another ajax library for this, so that's why I'm not using [`Bacon.fromPromise`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#bacon-frompromise)

You also may wonder why my consuming module wants the whole set instead of just the incremental update. If it were just appending rows that could be ok, but in my case it's an infinite scroll and it should draw data if both: 1. data is available *and* 2. area is on screen.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [.scan()](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#observable-scan) method. And also you will need a stream that emits items of one page, you can create it with [.repeat()](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#bacon-repeat).

Here is a draft code (sorry not tested):

```
var itemsPerPage = Bacon.repeat(function(index) {
  var pageNumber = index + 1;
  if (pageNumber < PAGE_LIMIT) {
    return Bacon.fromCallback(function(callback) {
      // your method that talks to the server 
      getDataForAPage(pageNumber, callback); 
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

var allItems = itemsPerPage.scan([], function(allItems, itemsFromAPage) {
  return allItems.concat(itemsFromAPage);
});


// Here you go
allItems.onValue(function(allUnicorns){
  console.log("Got "+ allUnicorns.length +" Unicorns");
  // ... some real display work
});
```

As you noticed, you also won't need `.onValue(function(){})` hack, and `curPage` external state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `flatMap` and `fold`. When dealing with network you have to remember that the data can come back in a different order than you sent the requests - that's why the combination of fold and map.

```
var pages = Bacon.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5])
var requests = pages.flatMap(function(page) {
  return doAjax(page)
  .map(function(value) {
    return {
      page: page,
      value: value
    }
  })
}).log("Data received")

var allData = requests.fold([], function(arr, data) {
  return arr.concat([data])
}).map(function(arr) {
  // I would normally write this as a oneliner
  var sorted = _.sortBy(arr, "page")
  var onlyValues = _.pluck(sorted, "value")
  var inOneArray = _.flatten(onlyValues)
  return inOneArray
})

allData.log("All data")

function doAjax(page) {
  // This would actually be Bacon.fromPromise($.ajax...)

  // Math random to simulate the fact that requests can return out
  // of order
  return Bacon.later(Math.random() * 3000, [ 
    "Page"+page+"Item1", 
    "Page"+page+"Item2"])
}
```

http://jsbin.com/damevu/4/edit

Comment: If you need the data to arrive in order. You can replace `flatMap` with `flatMapWithConcurrencyLimit`.